# Using mysqli->fetch_assoc() - Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I recently found myself in this dilemma while programming a chunk of my application.
I get the following error: `Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`

However, my application is turning the result into an array before trying to either return it or echo it.
The code is inside a method definition. And yes, I have tried everything I could, including searching this site, including all the questions marked as duplicate. No awnsers.

Here is the code after I tried a solution:

```
public function lookupEmailByUsername($username)
        {
            $database = new mysqli(APP_DB_HOSTNAME, APP_DB_USERNAME, APP_DB_PASSWORD, APP_DB_DATABASE, APP_DB_PORT);
            $database->select_db("users"); // better safe than sorry

            $row = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = \"$username\";");

            if($row->num_rows == 1){
                $finalRow = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = \"$username\";");
                $finalRow->fetch_array();

                $finalresult = $finalRow['email'];

                return $finalresult; // Line where error occurs
            } else {

                $Logger = new logger();
                $Logger->logEvent("ERROR", "Could not find user $username for reverse lookup", true, 1);
                return null;
            }

        }
```

`logger()` is my logging class and it has no problems.

Code before I tried a solution:

```
public function lookupEmailByUsername($username)
        {
            $database = new mysqli(APP_DB_HOSTNAME, APP_DB_USERNAME, APP_DB_PASSWORD, APP_DB_DATABASE, APP_DB_PORT);
            $database->select_db("stories_users");

            if(!$database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = \"$username\";")){
                $logger = new logger();
                $logger->logEvent("ERROR", "Unable to execute search SQL for email lookup");
                return null;
            }
            $row = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = \"$username\";");


            if($row->num_rows == 1){
                $row->fetch_assoc();

                return $row['email'];
            } else {

                $Logger = new logger();
                $Logger->logEvent("ERROR", "Could not find user $username for reverse lookup", true, 1);
                return null;
            }

        }
```

But when I `return $row['email']`, the error occurs.
Doing a var dump like this: `var_dump($row->num_rows)` returns 1, which is exactly what I am looking for.  Why? Because if there is one row, it means there is one user. And my app doesn't allow duplicate users. This means the SQL is correct.

Why is `return $row['email']` outputting that error when I tried to use `fetch_array` and `fetch_assoc`? There is one row as described above, and `fetch_assoc` should have turned it into an array.

OPS: I just found that `row` is not an array:

```
if(is_array($row)){
                    echo "row is array";
                    exit;
                }
                else {
                    echo "row is not array";
                    exit;
                }
```

But I used `fetch_assoc`. Sorry, I'm new to MySQLi's object oriented part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()` **returns** an associative array. It doesn not convert the `mysqli_result` instance into one. So, you'll want to store the value returned from `fetch_assoc` in a variable (you could use `$row`, which would require no further modification in your code).

Comment: The first user contributed note helped me more than your answer. No one really wanted to help but that guy did it. Thank you to referring me to the last bit of the docs, which I completely missed. +1 if I could.